# Inside a bash script doing an ssh, automatically add the host only for certain known RSA keys

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I have a Chron job running a bash script that then SSH's to a my server.  But my server's IP address changes from time to time (my bash script has a way of finding looking up the new IP address).  But the problem is that then my bash script gets the "Authenticity of host can't be established ..." warning.  I don't want to use `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` because of *man-in-the-middle* attacks. However:

If the *RSA key* is identical to e.g. an *RSA key* already in the `known_host` file, or an *RSA key* that I've saved off in some other `MyServersPublicKey` file, then I assume it's my server and it just has a new IP.

The warning itself displays the *fingerprint* of the *RSA key* from the "unknown" host, not the *RSA key* itself.  I suppose I could save off the *RSA key* *fingerprint* of my host and then have my bash script consume the *fingerprint* from the warning and compare it to the saved off *fingerprint*.  But I'm wondering if anyone knows an easier way.

Do I have to write my own bash script for this, or is there something available?

Comment: I can't check right now, but maybe signing the host key can be helpful. (Having a new IP with the same key is not the critical part, you just get the fingerprint warning, right? It's having a new host key that is cause for concern.)

Comment: Well this is operation is automated in a chron-job, so my bash script gets the fingerprint warning, not me.  I need my bash script to decide if it's safe to log on or not.  If it's the same old RSA key, just with a new IP address, then it's safe.  If it's a different RSA key and a different IP address, well then I'd rather the chron job aborted the operation.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in comments, creating certificates (signed host keys) would help you to solve this issue (see manual page for `ssh-keygen`, chapter "Certificates" describing this procedure). Basically you would create a CA on server, sign the host keys and store the CA public key in your `known_hosts` such as:

```
@cert-authority * ssh-rsa AAAAB5W...
```

The other possibility would be to write up some bash script, which would add your IP in front of the host key in `known_hosts` (if you don't have hashed that file). Something like that should work:

```
sed -i -e "s/your_host/new_ip,your_host/" ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```